# How do I get LibreOffice to make titles for columns such that as I scroll down I see the titles instead of "A,B,C,..." for columns?

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice, 32-bit

By instead of "A,B,C,..." I mean the column letters you see in this screenshot:[image]

I am using LibreOffice 4.0.2 that I installed from the tarball of debian packages that I downloaded from the libreoffice website. If it is relevant I am running 32 bit 12.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You can split the header.

Drag the little black horizontal segment that is above the scroll bar, while dragging you will see an horizontal line moving. Or: Window->Split (as seen in the 2nd image). The split will happen above the cursor. This is the end result:

[image]

- You can also use freeze. Window -> Freeze.

[image]

And this is the end result (3 rows this time):

[image]

---

The main difference between the 2 is that split adds a second scroll bar so you have 2 windows. Freeze also works on 1 or more columns.

Answer (score 1):

You have to see the column names A,B,c... , it cannot be otherwise (I think) but you can add titles in a new line that you'll fix when scrolling down.

Add a new line and fill in your titles.
Then, in your example select cell B2 (the one just under your title line; B1 if you do not wish to keep the first column when you scroll) and select Window->Freeze. Done.

You can also split it  (Window->Split) if you want to specify the exact place you want to keep rather than the first lines/columns.
Best,